# error in quartz scheduler : java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket

Tags: quartz-scheduler, c3p0

We are getting the below warning/error in quartz scheduler. We are storing the jobs in Oracle DB. This is first time we saw the error. I have checked in many forums , not finding the correct resolution .Any idea on the issue ?

```
Nov 24, 2015 12:22:03 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection handleThrowable
WARNING: [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
Nov 24, 2015 12:22:03 `enter code here`PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection handleThrowable
WARNING: [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket ] which will not be reported to listeners!
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1200)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1155)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:279)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOCOMMIT(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:75)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:558)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3674)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3680)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.commit(NewProxyConnection.java:803)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:73)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.commit(Unknown Source)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.commitConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:3670)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3789)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.triggersFired(JobStoreSupport.java:2900)
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:336)

Nov 24, 2015 12:22:03 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection handleThrowable
WARNING: [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
Nov 24, 2015 12:22:03 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection handleThrowable
WARNING: [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket ] which will not be reported to listeners!
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1200)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1155)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:279)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOROLLBACK(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:68)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doRollback(T4CConnection.java:642)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.rollback(PhysicalConnection.java:3716)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.rollback(NewProxyConnection.java:855)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Answer (score 1):

We were experiencing the same error and it was caused by connection leak. We found out by using JMX interface of c3P0, discovered that the application did not return connections and also the test query c3p0.preferredTestQuery was bad, so all tested connections were dropped.

In other cases, this could be caused by closed connection from the database side, but the pool should be able to reconnect in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, though not exactly the same, because both the older Oracle JDBC driver ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0.jar and the newer ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar were on the classpath.  Once I removed the older (ojdbc14) driver, the problem was resolved.

Our error message was

```
WARN  [3048  ] - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection: [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
WARN  [3048  ] - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection: [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow ] which will not be reported to listeners!
java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:125) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0.jar:"Oracle JDBC Driver version - 10.1.0.2.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:162) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0.jar:"Oracle JDBC Driver version - 10.1.0.2.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:227) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0.jar:"Oracle JDBC Driver version - 10.1.0.2.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.throwOverflow(NumberCommonAccessor.java:6797) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0.jar:"Oracle JDBC Driver version - 10.1.0.2.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getInt(NumberCommonAccessor.java:121) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0.jar:"Oracle JDBC Driver version - 10.1.0.2.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getInt(OracleResultSetImpl.java:489) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0.jar:"Oracle JDBC Driver version - 10.1.0.2.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getInt(OracleResultSet.java:1605) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0.jar:"Oracle JDBC Driver version - 10.1.0.2.0"]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getInt(NewProxyResultSet.java:451) [c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.TypeInfo.extractTypeInfo(TypeInfo.java:93) [hibernate-core-5.1.2.Final.jar:5.1.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:269) [hibernate-core-5.1.2.Final.jar:5.1.2.Final]
```